# Change the HTML element in a Blazor application by pressing a button?

Tags: html, blazor, element, blazor-webassembly, htmlelements

I wanted to ask if it is possible to change the type of an HTML element in a Blazor application by pressing a button.
That I turn a normal text into a text input field for example.

I have a table where the first column has a button for each entry in the table.
My goal is that when you press the button, the fields turn into input fields in time, so you can edit the values.

This is just a quick photo edit, but this is how I imagined it.

[image: This is roughly how I imagined it]

Comment: @Henk Holterman, try to imagine a screen which displays a list of Contact objects in a tabular form (datagrid if you want). Each row in the datagrid display s an "Edit" button  in the left column, and the next two columns display "Name" and "PhoneNumber" in a string form. When you click on  the "Edit" button, the first column will now contain two buttons: "Save" and "Cancel", the "Name" column and the "PhoneNumber" column will show their values in an input element so that you can edit them. You can click the "Save" button to save the changes, or the  "Cancel" button to discard the changes.

Comment: "Does that "table" map to a list of (View)Models?" Why should you map to a list of models ? You map to a list of objects, as for instance list of Contact objects. As you may realize by now, the model is Contact. Hope this help...

Comment: I'm sure, you were... I'm always ready to help, though. I've answered the question even if @sideSky did not direct it at me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an index `array` to track the edit status of each company. When the `button` is clicked, the corresponding value in the index array will be toggled. If the value is set to `true`, the cell will display an `input` field where you can edit the company name. The updated name will be saved to the list.

Instead of using a simple string to store company information, you can create a class that contains multiple properties such as the company `name` and `location`..

Output: [image: Change table data by button in Blazor]

Demo: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/lil3olrf

Implementation:

```
@page "/"
<h3>Companies</h3>

<table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Company</th>
        <th scope="col">Location</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    @foreach (var company in Companies)
    {
        var index = Companies.IndexOf(company);
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                        @onclick="@(() => { Edits[index] = !Edits[index]; })">
                        @(Edits[index] ? "Back" : "Edit")
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (Edits[index])
                {
                    <input class="form-control" type="text"
                           style="background-color:lightyellow;"
                           value="@company.Name"
                           @oninput="@(e => { Companies[index].Name = e.Value.ToString(); })"/>
                }
                else
                {
                    @company.Name
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (Edits[index])
                {
                    <input class="form-control" type="text"
                           style="background-color:lightyellow;"
                           value="@company.Location"
                           @oninput="@(e => { Companies[index].Location = e.Value.ToString(); })"/>
                }
                else
                {
                    @company.Location
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>

<ul>
    @*Check realtime changes to Company names when you edit them*@
    @foreach (var company in Companies)
    {
        <li>@company.Name: @company.Location</li>
    }

</ul>

@code {

    private List<Company> Companies { get; set; } = new List<Company>
    {
        new Company("Globex Corporation", "Germany"),
        new Company("Soylent Corp", "Switzerland"),
        new Company("Umbrella Corporation", "Netherlands")
    };

    private bool[] Edits { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Edits = new bool[Companies.Count];
    }

    public class Company
    {
        public Company(string name, string location)
        {
            Name = name;
            Location = location;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would it work if my Company was a class and not just a string and thus have multiple values to edit in the table?

Comment: I updated the answer using a class instead of string. This way you can add more properties and change together with company name when you toggle the edit button.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic component and demo page to demonstrate how you can do this.  There's a component and a demo page.

```cs
@page "/"
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-dark" disabled="@isEdit" @onclick="GoEdit">Edit</button>
    @if (this.isEdit)
    {
        @EditControl
    }
    else
    {
        @ViewControl
    }
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ViewControl { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment EditControl { get; set; }

    protected string disabled => isEdit ? "disabled": "";
    protected bool isEdit { get; set; }
    private void GoEdit(MouseEventArgs e)
        => isEdit = !isEdit;
}
```

And a demo page:

```cs
@page "/Demo"
<h3>EditorTest</h3>
<CascadingValue Value="model">
    <EditForm EditContext="editContext">
        <EditFormState @ref="editFormState" EditStateChanged="EditStateChanged"></EditFormState>
        <div>
            <SwitchedEditorComponent>
                <EditControl>
                    Email: <InputText @bind-Value="model.Email" placeholder="Enter your Email Address"></InputText>
                </EditControl>
                <ViewControl>
                    Email: <InputText @bind-Value="model.Email" disabled></InputText>
                </ViewControl>
            </SwitchedEditorComponent>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
</CascadingValue>


@code {

    private dataModel model { get; set; } = new dataModel();
    private EditFormState editFormState;
    private EditContext editContext;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        this.editContext = new EditContext(model);
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private void EditStateChanged(bool editState)
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public class dataModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```